# Python String to File

Tags: python, json, pandas, string

I am using a module called PyAttck to pull data and i have the below code:

```
from pyattck import Attck

attack = Attck()

for technique in attack.enterprise.techniques:
    print(technique.id)
    print(technique.name)
    for subtechnique in technique.subtechniques:
        print(subtechnique.id)
        print(subtechnique.name)
```

This allows me to print the data and looking at the type of each of these they are all <class 'str'>. Is there a way i can export these into a CSV or JSON File?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would flatten the data, then use a simple function to write to the file:

```py
# your data structure
attck_data = [
    {'id': '0', 'name': 'technique1', 'subtechniques': [
        {'id': '0', 'name': 'subtechnique0'},
        {'id': '1', 'name': 'subtechnique1'},
        {'id': '2', 'name': 'subtechnique2'},
    ]},
    {'id': '1', 'name': 'technique2', 'subtechniques': [
        {'id': '3', 'name': 'subtechnique3'},
        {'id': '4', 'name': 'subtechnique4'},
    ]},
]

# list comprehension to shape the data into a usable format
attck_flat = [{'id': technique['id'],
               'name': technique['name'],
               'sub_name': subtechnique['name'],
               'sub_id': subtechnique['id']}
              for technique in attck_data
              for subtechnique in technique['subtechniques']]

# let's see the new data
from pprint import pprint
pprint(attck_flat)
```

NOTE: I used a list of dictionaries to assume the data structure of the `Attck` class because the way you have it is not reproducible, i.e. `technique.id` instead of `technique['id']`.

Your code would look like this instead:

```py
attck_flat = [{'id': technique.id,
               'name': technique.name,
               'sub_name': subtechnique.name,
               'sub_id': subtechnique.id}
              for technique in attack.enterprise.techniques
              for subtechnique in technique.subtechniques]
```

Output:

```py
[{'id': '0', 'name': 'technique1', 'sub_id': '0', 'sub_name': 'subtechnique0'},
 {'id': '0', 'name': 'technique1', 'sub_id': '1', 'sub_name': 'subtechnique1'},
 {'id': '0', 'name': 'technique1', 'sub_id': '2', 'sub_name': 'subtechnique2'},
 {'id': '1', 'name': 'technique2', 'sub_id': '3', 'sub_name': 'subtechnique3'},
 {'id': '1', 'name': 'technique2', 'sub_id': '4', 'sub_name': 'subtechnique4'}]
```

From here you can use one of my commonly used json/csv writers

json:

```py
# funciton to write json files
import json
def write_json(data, path: str, indent=4):
    with open(path, 'w') as file:
        json.dump(data, file, indent=indent)

write_json(attck_flat, './attck.json')
```

Output:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "0",
        "name": "technique1",
        "sub_name": "subtechnique0",
        "sub_id": "0"
    },
    {
        "id": "0",
        "name": "technique1",
        "sub_name": "subtechnique1",
        "sub_id": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "0",
        "name": "technique1",
        "sub_name": "subtechnique2",
        "sub_id": "2"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "technique2",
        "sub_name": "subtechnique3",
        "sub_id": "3"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "technique2",
        "sub_name": "subtechnique4",
        "sub_id": "4"
    }
]
```

csv:

```py
# function to write csv files
import csv
def write_csv(data, path: str):
    with open(path, 'w') as file:
        # get all the keys
        fieldnames = set().union(*data)
        writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames,
                                lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(data)

write_csv(attck_flat, './attck.csv')
```

Output:

```
sub_name,name,id,sub_id
subtechnique0,technique1,0,0
subtechnique1,technique1,0,1
subtechnique2,technique1,0,2
subtechnique3,technique2,1,3
subtechnique4,technique2,1,4
```